# Pushing a project to a private repository error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, github

I am trying to push a Unity project on a github repository but I got an error. I tried all the "helpful" commands I found on google but none of those commands solved it.

The commands I typed in the terminal:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit"
git remote add origin "myrepolink"
git push -u origin "mybranch"
```

But instead of uploading my project I get this error:

```
! [rejected]        first_part -> first_part (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'myrepolink'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

"first_part" is my branch.

Comment: Your remote repository is not empty

Comment: Hi Visual Studio has an inbuilt tool called Team Explorer that can be used to push projects to github

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a tool called Team Explorer you can use to push projects to a remote repository located in Github. Visual Studio uploads the projects with a default configuration of private and github will clone the repository and make it private. Follow the steps below to push your projects to your github. Make sure you have your project open in Visual Studio.

1. Click on **View** and find **Team Explorer** then click on it to show the Team Explorer window and then click on Home. The window should look similar to the screenshot below.
   [image]
2. In the above window click on **Git Changes** and you should see an option to create a new Github repository like on the screenshot shown below.
   [image]
3. In the above window click on **Create Git Repository** and you should see the window below to create either a **local Git repository** or **Create a new Github repository**. Check the screenshot below for more details.
   [image]

Specify your github details and your good to go, happy coding.

Comment: This doesn't address the errors in any way

Comment: Hi @Bolov, am pretty sure the unity project is being developed from the visual studio IDE and OP would spare himself all the git command line headaches by simply using Team Explorer which is in built into Visual Studio.

Answer (score -3):

Being a MacBook user, I solved it by installing git

```
brew install git
```

(here you have to install homebrew first)

and then using these commands:

```
git config --global user.name "your github username"
git config --global user.email "your github email"
git clone "your github repository"
```

paste all the files in the cloned repository

```
git add .
git commit -m "your commit"
git push
```

now it s asking about your GitHub credentials and then all your unity project is pushed on GitHub.

:*

Comment: this answer doesn't seem to be correlated to the question. In your question `git` is clearly installed as the errors you get are from `git`. And this answer doesn't address the errors you get in the question at all. If you really get the errors from the question, then this answer does nothing to solve that situation at all.